# Get My Own Facebook User Access Tokens

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Within my facebook account, I see on my "App Settings" page here: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications that I have several "apps you use" such as: tripadvisor and 8tracks

How do I get my facebook "user access token" for each of those apps?

I don't own those apps, but surely I can retrieve my own personal "User access token" for each of the apps within my facebook account, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - you can not do this. The access token is the association between your user and the application. It "belongs" to you just as much as it belongs to the application.

Think of it this way - if you *were* to obtain that access token, you would be able to perform actions as if it were the application performing those actions on your behalf. Any action performed using that token would be attributed to the application. You could "spam yourself" and any reports would be directed at the application that created that content.

The tokens are used for security - not only for *your* security but also of the application.